# Show that $(x, y] \subset \mbox{int}\; C$ where C is a convex set

Tags: calculus, self-learning

> Given $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a convex set, $x \in \overline{C}$ and $y \in \mbox{int} \;C$. 
>   Show that $(x, y] \subset \mbox{int}\; C$.

I know the definition about convex set and I know that I need to prove for all point $p \in (x,y]$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $ p \in B(p,\delta) \subset C$.
But I couldn't to prove this. I was thinking this a long time because this is apparently easy.

Comment: Hint: if $B[x; 0] = \lbrace x \rbrace \subseteq \overline{C}$, and $B[y; r] \subseteq \overline{C}$, then $$B[\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y; \lambda 0 + (1 - \lambda)r] \subseteq \overline{C}.$$

Comment: This is actually true in any normed linear space. Finite dimensionality is not used in my answer below.

Comment: Let me add that I have explicitly found $\delta$ for a given  $p$.  That is the reason the proof looks long.

Comment: @TheoBendit If I couldn't prove your statement. Now, if this is true, the result follows because with this you show that every point in the segment $(x,y]$ is the center of a ball that is contained in $C$.

Comment: @WilliamBischoff Take a point $p \in B[\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y; \lambda 0 + (1 - \lambda)r]$, and think about the ray $\overrightarrow{xp}$ from $x$ to $p$. Try to find a point $q$ along that ray such that $p = \lambda x + (1 - \lambda) q$ (i.e. solve this equation for $q$). See if you can show $q \in B[y; r]$.

Comment: @TheoBendit $p = \lambda x + (1 - \lambda )q $ we have $q = \dfrac{p-\lambda x}{1-\lambda}$. So, $$ || q - y|| = || \dfrac{p-\lambda x - (1-\lambda) y}{1-\lambda}|| = \dfrac{1}{1-\lambda}|| p - (\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)|| < \dfrac{1}{1-\lambda}(1-\lambda)r = r.$$
So $q \in B[y; r]$.

Comment: But, I still confused what I need to show for get the result.

Comment: @WilliamBischoff So, since $q \in B[y; r] \subseteq \overline{C}$, and $x \in \overline{C}$, we have $p \in \overline{C}$, proving the result from my first comment.

Comment: @TheoBendit I think that I got it. Thanks so much. I will try write this one today.

Answer (score 0):

I have copied the following from some notes I had, so the notations are slightly different. I leave it to you to complete the argument using Theorem 2. (Drawing a picture will help in understanding what $\rho$ is).

Theorem 1

Let $C$ be a bounded convex set in $\mathbb R^{k}$
with non-empty interior. Let $x\in C^{0}.$ If $\left\Vert u\right\Vert
=1$ then there is a unique number $\rho =\rho (u)$ such that $x+ru\in C$ if $%
0\leq r<\rho $ and $x+ru\notin C$ if $r>\rho .$

Proof: let $\rho =\inf \{r>0:x+ru\notin C\}.$ It is easy to see that $\rho
\in (0,\infty ).$ If $0\leq r<\rho $ then $x+ru\in C$ by definition. If $%
r>\rho $ and $x+ru\in C$ then, for any $t\in \lbrack \rho ,r)$ we have $x+tu=%
\frac{r-t}{r}x+\frac{t}{r}(x+ru)\in C$ by convexity. Thus, $\{r>0:x+ru\notin
C\}$ does not intersect $[\rho ,r).$ We already know that it does not
intersect $[0,\rho )$ and hence its infimum must be at least $r$ which means 
$\rho \geq r.$ This is a contradiction.

Theorem 2

If $C,x,u,\rho $ are as above then $x+ru\in C^{0}$ if $0\leq r<\rho $ and $%
x+ru\notin C^{e}$ if $r>\rho $ (where $C^{e}$ is the exterior of $C).$

Proof: let $0\leq r<\rho .$ There exists $\delta >0$ such that $B(x,\delta
)\subset C.$ Let $r<s<\rho .$ If $0<\epsilon <(1-\frac{r}{s})\delta $ we
claim that $B(x+ru,\epsilon )\subset C.$ If $y\in B(x+ru,\epsilon )$ then $%
y=(1-\frac{r}{s})z+\frac{r}{s}(x+su)$ where $z$ is defined by this last
equation. If we show that $z\in B(x,\delta )$ it would follow that $z$ and $%
(x+su)$ both belong to $C$ and hence that $y\in C.$ This would complete the
proof of the claim. We have $\left\Vert z-x\right\Vert =\left\Vert \frac{y-%
\frac{r}{s}(x+su)}{(1-\frac{r}{s})}-x\right\Vert $

$=\left\Vert \frac{y-\frac{r}{s}(x+su)-(1-\frac{r}{s})x}{(1-\frac{r}{s})}%
\right\Vert =\left\Vert \frac{y-ru-x}{(1-\frac{r}{s})}\right\Vert <\frac{%
\epsilon }{(1-\frac{r}{s})}<\delta .$ We have proved the first part of the
theorem.

Now let $r>\rho .$ Let $s\in (\rho ,r)$ and $\delta $ be as before. Let $%
\beta =\frac{s}{r}.$ Let $0<\eta <\frac{r-s}{r}\delta .$ We claim that $%
B(x+ru,\eta )\subset C^{c}$ and this would finish the proof. Let $v\in
B(x+ru,\eta )$ and suppose, if possible, $v\in C.$ Define $w$ by $x+su=\beta
v+(1-\beta )w.$ This would lead to the contradiction [that $x+su\in C$ (even
though $s>\rho )]$ if we show that $w\in B(x,\delta ).$ However, $\left\Vert 
\frac{x+su-\beta v}{1-\beta }-x\right\Vert =\left\Vert \frac{x+su-\beta
v-(1-\beta )x}{1-\beta }\right\Vert =\left\Vert \frac{\beta x+su-\beta v}{%
1-\beta }\right\Vert =\frac{\beta }{1-\beta }\left\Vert x+\frac{s}{\beta }%
u-v\right\Vert =\frac{\beta }{1-\beta }\left\Vert x+ru-v\right\Vert <\eta 
\frac{\beta }{1-\beta }<\delta .$ The proof is now complete.

Take $u$ to be $\frac {y-x} {\|y-x\|}$ in theorem 2. (The roles of $x$ and $y$ are switched).

Comment: Thanks Kavi Rama Murthy. I will read your proof with more attention because this is so hard for me. I can't understand all which you wrote above. Thanks so much.